# Возможно ли написать свое Vk Apps приложение используя Java?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Возможно ли написать Vk Apps приложение используя Java?

Comment: Если коротко отвечая на ваш вопрос, то: `Да`

Comment: смотря, что вы там хотите делать. у `vk` только определенное количество запросов к их `API` бесплатное.